# Converting absolute times to relative in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

Here's the problem :

I have a list of events with their absolute times :-

```
[0, 10, 30, 50, ... ]
```

My task is to take a subset of this list and make times relative

```
[0, 10, 20, 20,....]
```

I'm doing something like this right now:-

```
for element in list :

   if(some criteria) :

       append the element to new empty list

result = []
result.append(new_list[0])
for x in xrange(len(new_list) - 1)
    result.append(new_list[i + 1] - new_list[i])
```

Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is there a particular performance problem with what you have?

Comment: Nothing significant.I still want to avoid going through the loop twice. If that's possible

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `zip` and *list slicing*
:

```
relative_times = [b - a for a, b in zip(times, times[1:])]
```

**Example:**

```
times = [0, 10, 30, 50]
relative_times = [b - a for a, b in zip(times, times[1:])]
# [10, 20, 20]
```